# validation rule for text and picklist

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I am working on a validation rule where I have 2 fields, one picklist and one text field.

I want to throw an error to the text field when someone tries to manually enter abc, def, xyz.

So far I have this

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(picklist_field__c , 'abc, def,xyz'),
    text_field__C, 
    null 
)
```

Comment: Validation rules cannot update fields, they only prevent records from being saved when the given condiitons/formula evaluates to true. To update a field, you'd want to use a before-save flow (workflow rules and process builder are starting to become deprecated).

Comment: Basically, it just means, if anyone tries to enter something on that field, and it doesn't match the VR criteria, block it from saving.

Comment: Sorry my bad I dont want to update the field we just want to block the field if someone tries to update the text field to abc, def, and xyz.

Comment: Unfortunately VR doesn't support reflection (to be able to read available picklist values) so you could make formula dynamic. Instead, you should edit VR to include all valid values like mentioned by @cropredy

Answer (score 0):

You would do the following

```
OR(Text_Field__c='abc',
   Text_Field__c='def',
   Text_Field__c='xyz')
```

or, something that looks cleaner and compiles in fewer bytes

```
'1' = CASE(Text_Field__c,
           'abc','1',
           'def','1',
           'xyz','1',
           '0')
```

Comment: With this formula how should I use picklist field cos abc,def,xyz are picklist values.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question.  Edit your post with a concrete example

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. i just edited the question.

Comment: If you edited the original question, I'm still in the dark as to the requirement. Are you trying to validate the text field's entry or the picklist entry? If the latter, are you trying to put the error into the text field?  If the latter, VR can't do this

Comment: I am validating the text field's entry and show error on the text fiel.

Comment: then my answer is correct- configure the VR to put the error on the text field (as opposed to any other field or top of page)

Comment: Thanks ! The VR works! Can you tell me why did you use Case function?

Comment: It is easier to edit over time,it compiles into fewer bytes as there is a limit of 5000 compiled bytes. As a service to the Community-mark the answer as accepted if it did solve your issue